# Подробное описание причин закрытия вопроса в web и мобильных приложениях

Tags: дефект, локализация, мобильное-приложение

Наблюдается совершенно разный текст в подробном описании причин закрытия.

Web:

> [image: web]

iOS:

> [image: iOS]

Для уже закрытых вопросов присутствует такой вариант например:

> [image: iOSclosed]

Android:

> [image: Android]

При этом вариант "не по теме" не имеет перевода. А в Android версии ещё добавка про "слишком стар".

Comment: М-м, iOS! А у **уже закрытых вопросов** причина закрытия у вас переведена?

Comment: @D-side там в заголовке добавляется суффикс `[closed]`, снизу по английски `closed as too broad`, например. А при клике комбинация русского-английского текста (добавил в вопрос).